# Cross Domain Android java

Tags: java, android, http, post, request

I am making an application for android, i need to make a request to www.example.com address using java. the problem is that I need to send POST parameters and i've been searching some info and i found something about cross-domain or something like that. Could someone help me to get to the request and get answer?

I tried to do the following code but not working:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "val"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

SOLUTION:::::::::::::

```
  try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com");

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "val"));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", "val2"));


                UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                        postParameters);
                post.setEntity(formEntity);

                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                        //inputStreamToString method
                    String data = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity()
                            .getContent());
                    return data;
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

inputStreamToString Method

```
private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String s = "";
        String line = "";

        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                s += line;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Return full string
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code . What does not work? Does it crash?

Comment: I resolve the problem by replace List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1); for ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-domain POST applies to web browsers submitting forms, not to HTTP in general. Browsers will not post across domains as a security policy. It does not apply to your case.

Comment: Great answer its true, i resolve the problme... i replace List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1); 
for
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();